# how to extract columns from a text file with bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like this.

```
 res          ABS   sum     
 SER A   1   161.15 138.3  
 CYS A   2    66.65  49.6  
 PRO A   3    21.48  15.8  
 ALA A   4    77.68  72.0  
 ILE A   5    15.70   9.0  
 HIS A   6    10.88   5.9
```

I would like to extract the names of first column(res) based on the values of last column(sum). I have to print resnames if sum >25 and sum<25. How can I get the output like this?

Comment: Per the conversation in the comments, can you clarify when you actually want resnames printed?  No number can be both less than 25 and greater than 25.  Do you want resnames printed if `sum != 25`, or do you want it printed if, for instance, `sum < 25 OR ABS > 25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}{if($5 != 25) print $1}' bla.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this with a `while read` loop in `bash`, it's easier, and most likely faster, to use `awk`

```
awk '$5 != 25 { print $1 }'
```

Note that your logic `print resnames if sum >25 and sum<25` is the same as `print if sum != 25`.

Comment: Sum > 25 *and* sum < 25 leaves nothing. Or would.

Comment: @TimPote: So 25 is meanwhile > 25 and < 25?

Comment: @userunknown Ah I see.  Apply actual boolean logic.  Sorry I parsed that as what he *meant* not what he actually *said*.  Yeah actual boolean logic would say that he needs to print nothing.

Comment: Mh, yes, but what he meant might be two functions, one which selects the lower, and one which selects the higher values, but not both at the same time. However - from your sample code it is trivial to make 2 specialized ones. What's about the headline?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `awk`. Its a simple tool for processing columns of text (and much more). Here's a simple [awk tutorial](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html) which will give you an overview. If you want to use it within a bash script, then [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/) tutorial should help.

Run this on the command line to give you an idea of how you could do it:

```
> echo "SER A   1   161.15 138.3" | awk '{ if($5 > 25) print $1}'
> SER
> echo "SER A   1   161.15 138.3" | awk '{ if($5 > 140) print $1}'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do 
v=($line)
sum=${v[4]}
((${sum/.*/} >= 25)) && echo ${v[0]}
done < file
```

You need to skip the first line.

Since bash doesn't handle floating point values, this will print 25 which isn't exactly bigger than 25.

This can be handled with calling bc for arithmetics.

```
tail -n +2 ser.dat | while read line
do  
  v=($line)
  sum=${v[4]}
  gt=$(echo "$sum > 25" | bc) && echo ${v[0]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the good old cut?
:)

say you would like to have the second column,

```
cat your_file.txt | sed 's, +, ,g' | cut -d" " -f 2
```

what is doing sed in this command?
cut expects columns to be separated by a character or a string of fixed length (see documentation).

Comment: Just to let you know, there are a few problems with this solution. First of all, it's a prime example of a [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  sed can work on files without the need for the pipe.  Second, awk doesn't have the field separator limitations of cut, so you could do the same with a single `print $2` in awk without the need for sed.  Third, it doesn't do what the OP asks.  They wanted to *conditionally* print the second field.  Yours *always* prints the second field.